# How do you find the enumeration of $\mathbb N^3$

Tags: cardinals

I turned it into a three-dimensional array where I have values (i,j,k) but I need to find a function that enumerates $\mathbb N$ x $\mathbb N$ x $\mathbb N$. I found the function for the enumeration of $\mathbb N^2$ which was $(((i+j)(i+j+1))/2) +j$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Maybe you want to take the tour (http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)
What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?
Also, using MathJax would be nice (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
Maybe visualizing the construction for $\mathbb N^2$ helps in finding one for $\mathbb N^3$. Or you just iterate the one you have found.
Also, what's the connection to cardinals? Please read the tag description before using it.

Comment: What "enumeration of $N^2$" means?

Comment: Let's say you have a bijection $\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ : $f(i,j)$, then to have a bijection $\mathbb{N}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ : $g(i,j,k)$ simply define $g(i,j,k) = f(f(i,j),k)$

Comment: What if you just found an injection $f: \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N} \, ; \, (a,b,c) \mapsto 2^a3^b5^c$?

Answer (score 1):

If an enumeration of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is given by
$$ \varphi:(i,j)\mapsto \binom{j}{1}+\binom{i+j+1}{2} $$
then an enumeration of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is given by
$$ \psi:(i,j,k)\mapsto \binom{k}{1}+\binom{k+j+1}{2}+\binom{k+j+i+2}{3} $$
or by
$$ \eta:(i,j,k)\mapsto \varphi(i,\varphi(j,k)) $$
for instance.

Comment: Explain the downvote.